Java.lang.NullPointerException: cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "engine" is null . Using Java 17 and spring boot 3
While migrating to jdk17 I am facing this issue.
I have a method as :
private String fun(String value, String mtcn) { 
    String encodedvalue=""; 
    ScriptEngineManager manager=new ScriptEngineManager(); 
    ScriptEngine engine=manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); 
    try{
        encodedvalue=engine.eval("encodeURIComponent('"+value+"')").toString();
    } 
    catch(ScriptException e){
        Log.error(); 
    } 
    return encodedvalue;
}

This error is coming as string is null. Please help
I have also tried using graalvmjs engine but same error is coming.
